# select chan, why not block? but print like dead loop

Tags: go

I think if *chan* have no data, *for select* should block, but it not, what is wrong?

this my code

```
func TestSelect(t *testing.T)  {
    ch := make(chan int, 10)
    ch <- 1
    ch <- 2
    ch <- 3
    ch <- 4

    close(ch)
    for {
        select {
        case c := <-ch:
            fmt.Println("out... ", c)
        default:
            fmt.Println("sleep... ")
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }
}
```

result, dead loop print

```
time="2020-12-19 10:50:31.9556" level=info msg="save log day ====  30"
=== RUN   TestAaa
out...  1
out...  2
out...  3
out...  4
out...  0
out...  0
out...  0
out...  0
out...  0
out...  0
out...  0
out...  0
out...  0
out...  0
out...  0
out...  0
out...  0
out...  0
out...  0
out...  0
out...  0
out...  0
out...  0
.
.
.
```

Comment: i think if `default` case was selectd, if should print `sleep... `

Comment: Receive on a closed channel returns the zero value of the channel element type. The operation does not block.  Remove `close(ch)` to make the test case deadlock.  Use `for c := range ch  {  fmt.Println("out... ", c) }` to break out of the loop after printing the values sent to the channel.

Comment: yeah,,, i try it,.  if `chan`  not close , it might block,  occor error `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`  , your anwson is verfy helpfu for me,  thank you verfy much

Answer (score 1):

You can always get default zero value from close channel